# Hamburger Icon not showing for second time when I go to other Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

First I have made a button navigation with three Fragments in Main Activity and I made a Hamburger Icon in Toolbar , when I run the app , hamburger icon work correctly for the first time
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TjUY.jpg)
but when I go to other fragments or comeback to home fragment, there is no hamburger icon.
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8oUP.jpg)

and here is my codes :

**Main Activity :**

```
package ir.cuproid.newamouzesh

import android.app.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


         val bottomNavigationView= findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
          val navController =findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)

          val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.firstFragment,R.id.secondFragment,R.id.thirdFragment))

            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
           bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)


        val drawerLayout : DrawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout)

        val nav_view : NavigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        toggle= ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)

        toggle.syncState()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

**Main Activity XML code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="673dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [FirstFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)


            setMenuVisibility(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            FirstFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't [following the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) which specifically states you shouldn't be using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`? Or the [documentation on the ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar) which indicates how you should be overriding `onSupportNavigateUp()` (and not `onOptionsItemSelected()`)? Do your fragments call `supportActionBar` or `setSupportActionBar()` anywhere?

Comment: I don't want to use fragments and bottom navigation fragments in `DrawerLayout` , I want to add other things like a message in `DrawerLayout` . now how can I connect xml code and layout to `Actionbar` ? @ianhanniballake

Comment: What does the contents within your `NavigationView` (what actually appears in the drawer) have to do with anything I mentioned with how you should be hooking up your hamburger button? Those are completely independent things

Comment: sorry my English is not so good , I used a tutorial from youtube, so I will change my mistakes with those documentations , thanks for that , the last part of your question : Do your fragments call `supportActionBar` or `setSupportActionBar( )` anywhere ? if I understand correctly , no  I didn't do this , I added my fragment code. @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

Add these line on fragment too, and make new **toggle** for it.

```
toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)

        toggle.syncState()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```